# Notation for a matrix with same vector in columns

Tags: matrices, notation

Is there a notation for a matrix which columns are the same vector?

$$
x = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}x_1 & x_2 & x_3\end{array}\right]^{T} \\
y = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}x & x & x\end{array}\right]
$$

Is there a proper notation for $y$?

Comment: Maybe $[1,1,1]\otimes x$ ? I think maybe it is $\sum_i e_i\otimes x$. I don't have full insight in how the kronecker product relates to the tensor product, but i think both can be see as "vector times vector".

Comment: $Y=x1^T$ is often useful.  Here $1$ is a column vector, whose elements are all equal to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation you have for $y$ is fine. It's common [block matrix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've seen it wrote like this $$\left(\begin{matrix} |&|&|\\x&x&x\\|&|&|\end{matrix}\right)$$ The form you suggested doesn't seems right to me, but I could be wrong!